# Approximating Lines to Floor plan contours

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++, image-processing

I am using OpenCV-C++ and 1) I want to approximate the detected contours using findContours by only horizontal or vertical lines, and not by curves, as in floor plans. So can you suggest a method for the same.

2) Is there a way to remove smaller contours like tree borders, which can automate the process for every image, since removing the smaller areas with findContours() can lead to elimination of walls with smaller dimensions.

http://property.magicbricks.com/microsite/buy/provident-welworth/floor-plan.html

Comment: It's probably better to use [`HoughLines`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghlines#houghlines) instead.

Comment: @RogerRowland We cannot use HoughLines since the contours are broken and with structures like windows and basin attached to the walls, they sort of extend from the lines, disrupting its straightness.

Answer (score 0):

On what sort of image do you use the find contours? I assume you did follow this example..
[findContour example](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html)
if not, please clarify.
However, why not try to first find all horizontal and vertical edges with the corresponding filters? Afterwards you can still try to find contours with the findContours function. Or you can use the hough transform, also available in opencv. [hough lines](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html) within the hough lines you can easily eliminate smaller line segments.

for 2) what do youi mean by tree borders? you mean the contours of a tree on an image? it would be very helpful if you could provide an example image.

Cheers

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: ok, sorry for that. But I am not allowed to comment, because I don't have enough reputations. I thought I could give him some hints on how to solve his problem.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to sound like a douche or discourage you, the SO review panel adds that comment automatically when flagging things. You should work on building up a little more rep so you can comment.

Comment: I have such a floor plan as in any one of the three images.http://property.magicbricks.com/microsite/buy/provident-welworth/floor-plan.html I have found out the contours of the walls. But since its a raster image, contours can mix form curves at the L shaped corners. Thus, since a floor plan consists only of horizontal and vertical lines. I want to map those curves with only horizontal and vertical lines.